# GoPro webcam app is blocked

Tags: windows-10, webcam, gopro

I've got the GoPro Hero 9 and I'd like to use it in my Windows laptop.

I've followed all the steps described [here](https://community.gopro.com/s/article/GoPro-Webcam?language=en_US#faqwindows) but when I want to open the app I get this message:

[image: Blocked app message]

it says "Seems the app was blocked in the last session, Would you like to send a report?" and no matter if I press Yes or No, nothing happens and the app never opens.

I tried:

- Setting the app in my antivirus' exclusion list.
- Setting to run exclusively with my integrated graphics chip
- Setting to run exclusively with my discrete graphics card
- Running with windows' troubleshooter.
- Running as Admin
- With GoPro's cable
- With alternative cable
- To contact GoPro through twitter
- To contact GoPro through Discord (They "paused" the server... WTF?!)

Has anyone encounter with this problem?

Comment: This dialogue is generated by the application itself, without knowing why the error is displayed, it will be difficult to resolve the reason its displayed. What exactly is the title of the error dialog?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound the title doesn't say anything useful like "Tool of blocking reports"

Comment: Have you checked for updated software? Most orgs have a more standard way for contacting support than a Discord.

Comment: Yes @music2myear I've downloaded the latest app and have my GoPro firmware updated